# Why isn't Atom recognizing my regular expressions?

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I'm using Atom to format some text data for analysis (I know there are probably better ways of doing it than this so I'm all ears) but it doesn't seem to be recognizing my regular expression.

The text is POS tagged tokens with sentences being delineated with newlines, formatted as such:

```
good\tJJ\n
workout\tNN\n
.\t.\n
''\t''\n
\n
Perhaps\tRB\n
the\tDT\n
```

I was able to replace all of the tabs (`\t`) with a front slash (`/`) no problem, but I'm now trying to turn all newlines that DON'T delineate sentences with just a space. I tried `\S\n` and it "wasn't found". I also tried to highlight all delineating newlines with `^\n$` but there were only two matches and only at the end of the document.

Am I doing this wrong? My only usage of regex is with Python, so maybe there's just a different way to do it in Atom.

EDIT: I'm just giving up and gonna use Python to process it. Nothing suggested work. The search function seemed to just be bugging out in general (e.g. one search would not work but then if I closed the search function and reopened it, the same search would work) because it's a long file (700,000+ lines) despite it not being a large file, data-wise (6,235 KB). If anyone can recommend a large file text editor, though, it would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you distinguish new lines that delineate sentences from those that do? Can you also show the expected result from the given input?

Comment: Just an idea, maybe `(?<!\n)\n`?

Comment: Or perhaps `\t|\n(?=[ \t]*\S)` https://regex101.com/r/hcsjPn/1/

Comment: There must be an option like match multiline or something if `\r?\n\b` does not work.

Comment: @OrangeXenon54 are you using any packages for regex support?